# IBM Presence Insights sample store environment for demo purpose

Tags: ibm-cloud, sample-data, presenceinsights

How can I get access to the sample store environment mentioned in the [VT cycling demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARCqmQSPj08&feature=youtu.be)? We are planning for an internal demo in the company and looking forward to show some analytics data captured by Presence Insights platform. Please share the link. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the link under the YT video? http://www.ibm.com/mobilefirst/us/en/presence-insights.html The sample store is mentioned on that website

Comment: Yes. But the sample store environment is not available when I signed up as mentioned in the link.

Comment: In the video they only mention "getting the same capabilities as in this demo". Let me ask around whether the sample data is available for download.

Comment: You need to create your own site, there is no sample site available. It would be cool to have a demo/sandbox environment that gets reset every few hours though. Good idea!

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the link seems to be misleading, and gives the impression of a demo site, that can be downloaded. I will raise the issue with the development team and see if we cannot create something that fits the bill. However, I am sorry to say that I do not think this will be done in the next few days.